# How to change the one table column values with another table column values

Tags: sql

I have a customer table like
(cid, mobileno, mailno, officeno)
(1 , 123456789, 11, 111)

I have a number table like
(numcode,  mobileno)
(11 ,  1235879456)
(111 , 5478859987)

Now i want output like
(cid, mobileno,  mailno,  officeno)
(1, 123456789, 1235879456, 5478859987

can any one please answer?

Comment: Look up SQL `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find everything you need [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). If you want results ONLY when there's a match in BOTH tables, read about [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT T1.cid, T1.mobileno, T2.mobileno, T3.mobileno FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.mailno=T2.numcode JOIN T2 as T3 ON T1.officeno=T3.numcode;

T1 is a customer table, 
T2 is a number table

Check it first, I can't do it without database.